# Typescript: consider a generic type as Array

Tags: typescript

I encounter this case in my recent work, and I can't figure a good solution.
I hope some one can provide me tips with this ;)

I generated my types from a swagger to typescript parser.

It gave me types for all routes, looking like

```
type GetXXXCollection = {
  responseBody: XXXType[]
}
```

A linked that with axios to fetch

```
const fetchXXX = () => axios.get<GetXXXCollection.responseBody>(uri)
```

and it works just fine.

I'm trying to build a generic fetch to parse my data with something like

```
const fetchXXXParsed = (uri) => genericFetchThenParse<GetXXXCollection.responseBody>(uri)

const genericFetchThenParse = async <T>(uri) => {
   const res = await axios.get<T>(uri)

   // I want to map over my results
   res.data.map(...)

}
```

Is there a way to make `genericFetch` T type act like an array

Answer (score 0):

You need to strengthen the constraints of `T` to be an array.  This can be done by making sure it extends `unknown[]`:

```
import axios from "axios";

declare namespace GetXXXCollection {
  export type responseBody = { foo: number }[];
}

const fetchXXXParsed = (uri: string) => genericFetchThenParse<GetXXXCollection.responseBody>(uri)

const genericFetchThenParse = async <T extends unknown[],>(uri: string) => {
   const res = await axios.get<T>(uri)

   res.data.map(data => data);
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQwB7AgZzgMyhEcBEyqa+A3AFDkAmApgMYA2CUNcAdgiDWmAnawHEaMABpiAwhAYN6MVGzgBvcnDg0kkWHBgBPMKxY8IbNDQBCEKjrgBeJVggQAXOwCuIAEY0ocAL4BtAF0KX0o6YzR4TGE6AAsxEQAFZlMqWzgAClcoYBdInLYAcwBKWwA+OEKaNm9gOgAxGNiAFVjq5KhTAB4hUQkpGTo5YwA6Q0gTc0sdMqyc4rCI+CqanIam1vaU1jsENB02Ojgu5rUkGGqqDFc2AGs2CAB3NiCAGlns3Lh84CLSmwqylUcHCJnghnSCEeCGA8CI6BGVRgJw+80owMMIyoCBgCBGIAQYAy2Nx5TgJIQxQo5F8QA)